# Is it possible to see traveling light beams?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, thought-experiment, gamma-rays

As we all know the speed of light is the thing that allows us to see

Now let's imagine a beam of gamma rays from a Black hole just a few light years away passing through the solar system somehow was able to totally miss earth and every other observable thing,then lets tell if the space around the path of this beam was a somewhat perfect vacuum i.e. has no particles in it ,then would we ever be able to know that we escaped from a lion's den?

Comment: Please don't give the end point argument here if you do so then I will just tell you to imagine the same thing between inter-"Super cluster" travel which may and most likely is expanding at faster the speed of light so It wouldn't have any end point therefore ending this pre-argument.

Comment: Your question is more about epistomology versus ontology, and not really about physics.  Of course, if there is no interaction there is no way to know whether it was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the beam did not interact with anything, it would still have energy/momentum. According to GR, any energy/momentum distribution will curve spacetime around it. In principle, it should be possible to see the bending of the light of distant stars passing through the region as a small change in the apparent position of the stars.

I say "in principle" since the effect will be impossibly small for any realistic gamma ray beam.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the space -time curvature that I didn't mention but actually should have even though its effect would be just too small to detect as you too have mentioned therefore My own answer on the question is also Acceptable. So the down vote you possibly have given is unnecessary so please remove it if you don't to up vote it either.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer would be No.

Without any interations with other objects and the most clear path in the whole universe it would be nearly impossible or maybe even impossible to detect as light doesn't scatter/lose energy when it is travelling through a vacuum.However it could be that I am wrong and if so ,then please tell me the reasons for it and in a logical manner that a 13 yr old could possibly understand.

Thanks for hanging around!